# How to achieve similar layout to 365 Scores app in Swift? (Screenshot included)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I tried to achieve the below layout with a single tableviewbut failed.

The structure of the below screenshot is as follows:

- Date (Today):

  - My subscribed lists (My Teams & Games):

    - League name:

      - Actual match (Looks like a Tableview cell)

Please note that each level of the structure is dynamic in count depending on the matches of the day.

I tried implementing this with a tableview but couldn't figure out how to create nested sections. For example, at the top level I tried to make the sections headerView to represent the date but then I was forced to make the rest of the strucure inside a cell which is not the case for the app in the screenshot.

I am assuming the actual matches are the tableview cells since they are the ones that are swipe-able?

Please help me with some ideas.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to approach this... here are *just two* ideas:

[image]

[image]

As was mentioned in the comments on your other question - you really need to **start working on it**. If you run into ***specific*** problems, come back here with ***specific*** questions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already tried to replicate but I am struggling with how to keep track of the index of each section/row. For example, in the second picture you provided, how can I let the data source know how many cells of class 4 under each cell class 3. Also, How to let it know how many total cells of class 3 are under cells of class 2 and same goes for all of those under the section Header.    
I am currently creating a view model from the api supplying the data but I am struggling to map it correctly to the data source. Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: @Mbasa - that's what I mean by "***specific problems / specific questions***". Nobody here knows how you're getting your data, or how it's structured. Regardless of how you will end up *displaying* it, your first task is coding the structs / classes / dictionaries / arrays / etc from the data you receive.